# Android Studio GRADLE BUILD VERY SLOW

Tags: java, android, time, gradle, build

When I run my project in android studio , it takes long to compile,
it usually requires 3 - 5 minutes.

**In Gradle Console it stopping long time in:  :app:dexDebug**

How can I reduce the time ???

my bulild.gradle

```
apply plugin: 'com.android.application'
android {
 compileSdkVersion 23
 buildToolsVersion "23.0.1"

defaultConfig {
    applicationId "it.unical.mat.myapp"
    minSdkVersion 15
    targetSdkVersion 23
    versionCode 1
    versionName "1.0"
    multiDexEnabled true
}
buildTypes {
    release {
        minifyEnabled false
        proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
    }
 }
}
dependencies {
 compile 'com.android.support:multidex:1.0.0'
 compile fileTree(include: ['*.jar'], dir: 'libs')
 compile 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:23.0.1'
 compile 'com.android.support:support-v4:23.0.1'
 compile 'com.google.android.gms:play-services:8.1.0'
 compile files('libs/activation.jar')
 compile files('libs/gdata-analytics-2.1.jar')
 compile files('libs/gdata-core-1.0.jar')
 compile files('libs/gdata-spreadsheet-3.0.jar')
compile files('libs/jsr305.jar')
compile files('libs/mail.jar')
compile files('libs/guava-18.0.jar')
}
```

Comment: How long is your `build.gradle` file ? Do you have a lot of dependencies ?

Comment: It's definitely too much, but it's hard to tell what's the problem without seeing your Gradle setup. Try running your build with --debug to see if something causes delays.

Comment: @Maloubobola show my edits. up

Comment: Buy a faster computer?

Comment: Could you check which Gradle release you use?

Comment: 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:1.3.0' @fab

Comment: Upgrade your RAM capacity use 4GB+

Comment: How does your memory look like while your build is running?

Comment: Are you running Android Studio off your HDD/SSD or a network drive ?

Comment: @ThiagoPorciúncula memory usage is very high

Comment: @KoenDemonie I run Android Studio on SSD

Comment: @mc_marad How high? How many GB do you have? What is the usage in percentage during the build? if it's near 100%, a lot of swaping is happening and increasing your RAM will, in fact, help you out.

Comment: a) is your ssd fileld above 95% capacity ? b) when you are building, open task manager and see howmuch memory you have left. c) what is you internet speed ?

Comment: @ThiagoPorciúncula  I have 8gb of memory. during the bulid memory is 6gb and cpu usage id 100%

Comment: Then I don't think more RAM would help.